# Error in tile game action listener loop

Tags: java, arrays

This is my ActionListen class that adds actionlisteners to the buttons on the grid based on what number is on them. If I click a button next to the blank spot(TileGame.tile[x][y]==0), then the two buttons should swap, however, when I click a button, nothing happens.

Here is my code :

```
public class ActionListen
{
int x;
int y;
public ActionListen()
{
    for( x = 0 ; x <= 2 ; x++)
    {
        for( y = 0 ; y <= 2 ; y++)
        {
            if( x <2 && y <2)
            {
                if(TileGame.tile[x][y] !=0 && TileGame.tile[x+1][y] == 0)
                {
                    TileGame.tilebutton[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                            { 
                                TileGame.tile[x+1][y] = TileGame.tile[x][y];
                                TileGame.tile[x][y] = 0;
                                new DrawGame();
                            }
                        });
                }
                else if(TileGame.tile[x][y] !=0 && TileGame.tile[x][y+1] ==0)
                {
                    TileGame.tilebutton[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                            {
                                TileGame.tile[x][y+1] = TileGame.tile[x][y];
                                TileGame.tile[x][y] = 0;
                                new DrawGame();
                            }
                        });

                }
```

Comment: why are you doing everything in the constructor?

Comment: Why are you not adding listeners to the tile with coordinate (2, 2)? Why do you make a new DrawGame for each action performed?

Answer (score 0):

The code currently does not care about where the empty tile is placed. So you just swap the tile clicked with a fixed tile in the neighbourhood. This might be the blank one. But you should search for the blank tile (or store the blank tile coordinates somewhere accessible), and swap those coordinates, not just some random one.

Also maybe there should be a check if the blank tile is uberhaupt in the neighbourhood, aka can it be swapped?

```
TileGame.tile[x][y] = TileGame.tile[getXCoordinateBlankTile()][getYCoordinateBlankTile()];
TileGame.tile[getXCoordinateBlankTile()][getYCoordinateBlankTile()] = 0;
setXCoordinateBlankTile(x);
setYCoordinateBlankTile(y);
```